# check the dates in a list to get next date

Tags: sql, sql-server

questin on sql server,

i have a table which has some dates but i query those specific dates like this:

```
select* from dates where datein in('15/0/2019','16/08/2019','20/12/2019','01/01/2020')
```

now i want to get the dates which are greater than today which i can using a compare with getdate(), but after that i also want to show me two dates by jumping the date which is just after the getdate(),

let me know if i am unclear

so explaining again,

i have 10 dates in a list. - past, present, future dates

1. The first filter will show me the dates which are greater than today date
2. the second filter will show me 2 dates which match the first filter and excluding the immediate next date date, so the 3 and 4th will be displayed

at one point of time, only two dates will be visible

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD would all help your explanation.

Comment: What is the date `'15/0/2019`'? When is month 0?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this.  Assuming the dates are unique in your table:

```
select d.*
from dates d
where d.datein in (. . .) and
      d.datein > getdate()
order by d.datein asc
offset 1 row fetch first 2 rows only;
```

Comment: 15/0/2019 REFERS TO 1503/3019 - MY MISTAKE, BUT NOT EXACTLY THE OFFSET BECAUSE IT WILL ALWAYS ignore the first element, but based upon the logic that whatever date is after today, the nextone should be skipped

Comment: @user11606636 Mistake? Then correct it in the original post. And also specify what value(s) you want based on that sample list and at least 2 different sample values for Getdate() (i.e., as if you ran your script on different dates and times). This should not be a game of 1000 questions.